# 12.04 upgrade not working

Tags: 12.04

Help! I have upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04 but it doesn't pick up the keyboard so I cannot type in my login keyring password to do anything. I have tried a spare USB keyboard but this is not picked up either. Any if I put a USB stick in the menu comes up and I can open and edit a document - keyboard must work!
Any ideas?
I get an error message - cannot capture your keyboard so cannot get past 'Enter password to unlock your login keyring.'

Answer (score 1):

I have solved both keyboard and networking issues (keyboard not recognized and no network connection) by rolling back to kernel 3.0.0-15-generic-pae.

Just selected 3.0.0-15 in "Previous Linux Versions" section of GRUB menu.

If that works yuo couldalso uninstall newer kernel (sudo apt-get remove 3.2.0.24) and update GRUB (sudo update-grub).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. What Iam getting now is an error message - 'The application Compiz has closed unexpectedly.' The keyboard is now recognised but I just get the desktop background with no icons on it. I can't seem to get any up.How can i get to the GRUB menu?

Comment: to enter GRUB menu press shift during boot (just after bios screen). 

I even had to clean up my home directory from profile settigns but still got same error sometimes, but everything works ok.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, and can get around it by clicking cancel on the keyring login.
Not sure if that helps or not. Unity still not working for me though !!